# Missing before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code that I would like to style:

```
var dateString = val.date; // this display my blog post date e.g. "2013-09-02 15:04:50"
var split = dateString.split(' ');

output += '<div class="postxt">' (split[0] +" at "+ split[1]) '</div>';
```

How can I add a span or a div for both split0 & split1

Thanks

Comment: Why not just concatenating some HTML like you already do ?

Comment: Your braces should be pluses in the last line.

Comment: @tmh Maybe that's what's blocking OP. You should make an answer.

Comment: For those who might need to add comments for each results, this is my final code. Hope this helps others:

**output += '<div class="postxt">Posted on <span class="posval">' + split[0] + '</span> at <span class="posval">' + split[1] + '</span></div>';**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the SPAN to the HTML, the same way you do the DIV.

```
output += '<div class="postxt"><span class="date">' + split[0] + 
          '</span> at <span class="time">' + split[1] + '</span></div>';
```

You also need to use `+` to concatenate the HTML elements with the variables.

Comment: silly me I missed the + sign to concatenate the html element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your braces should be pluses in the last line:

```
output += '<div class="postxt">' + split[0] + " at " + split[1] + '</div>';
```

Note that you can leave the braces in, but they are neither required nor do they make any differences when concatenating strings:

```
output += '<div class="postxt">' + (split[0] + " at " + split[1]) + '</div>';
```

Add whatever divs, spans, style classes you want:

```
output += '<div class="postxt"><span class="foo">' + split[0] + "</span> at <span class="bar">" + split[1] + '</span></div>';
```

The error "Missing ... before statement" you got was only on the JavaScript level, it has nothing to do with adding further HTML elements.